# How to display message in ios app directly on screen, like ringer/mute display

Tags: ios

I want to display a message like tooltip in my app, it should be displayed right next to the item and on the screen.
It is like in the reminder app in iphone when we switch to another month, or rather like the ringer volume or mute indicator in iphone or ipad.

Is it possible to show message like that and hide it after some timeout or so?

Answer (score 1):

Try [TapkuLibrary](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary); it includes a class called `TKAlertView` which seems to do exactly this.